# Can you save a data type to a variable? (DataType t = Integer)?

Tags: java, reflection, types, type-conversion

In the classes I am coding, I tend to have to cast variables to other datatypes quite commonly. I wanted to make a method that could truncate this process. I wanted it to be something like this:

```
    public static Object typeCast(Object o, DataType type){
    if (o instanceof type){
        return (type) o;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

However, I know of no way to save a data type as a variable. Is this possible?

Comment: Look into reflection and `Class` objects.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, every `DataType` is a class which you can get from a object with `getClass()` at runtime. 
Saving the Class of a object is quite simple.

```
Class<Integer> clazz = Integer.class;
Object obj = Integer.valueOf(1);
clazz.instanceOf(obj); // will return true in that case.
```

You can use also do something like following to cast if possible or return null if not, which works for all classes and object you put in.

```
public static <T> T typeCast(Object o, Class<T> type) {
    if (type.isInstance(o)) {
        return type.cast(o);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work either (At least, that I can tell). Might I be calling the method wrong? I am doing this: int x = 5. typeCast(x, long);

Comment: Yes, you're doing it wrong. You've to call something like that `Integer x = typeCast(obj, Integer.class);`. Primitive data types can't be used. Always use the Class representation of them e.g. `Integer` for `int`, or `Double` for `double`.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the `Class` object:

```
public static Object typeCast(Object o, Class type){
    if (o instanceof type){
        return type.cast(o);
    }else{
        return Boolean.FALSE;
    }
}
```

where `type` is the class which you want `o` to be cast into.

This is not really useful though since you'll get an `Object` back. Generic methods may help you here but it is not yet clear what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: This doesn't compile.